# How do I find method calls?

Tags: java, netbeans

In NetBeans, how can I find out where methods are being called?

I have one particular method in a big project and can't find where its being called.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a **Find Usages** menu item when you right-click on a method name.

Or place your cursor on the method name and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (Find Usages) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (to show the Find Usages results).

Comment: Alt+u (by default, you can change it though) and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on the Corresponding Project and Click Find. Enter the method name and Click Find

Answer (score 1):

You should right click the method and look for something like ' Call stack'